# Hive: Whenever it fires a map reduce it gives me this error "Can not create a Path from an empty string", how do I debug?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using hive 0.10 and  when I do

```
hive -e "show tables", hive -e "desc table_name" it works!
```

but when I do something like `hive -e "select count(*) table_name` I am getting the exception below. Is there a way I can debug this? The same code worked in the previous cluster with a older version of hive and the new cluster is throwing this error.  What should be the right way to debug this kind of issues, did not find anything from google that solves the issue.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getHiveJobID(Utilities.java:382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.clearMapRedWork(Utilities.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:951)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:706)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:613)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

Comment: I came across the same error. The cause was very different for me. Querying a "view" in Athena using Spark seems to not yet be supported. 

It will throw a 'Can not create a Path from an empty string' exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I looked up the log file and in my case the table is an external table referring to a directory located on hdfs. This directory contains more than 300000 files. So while reading the files it was throwing an out of memory exception and may be for this reason it was getting an empty string and throwing 'Can not create a Path from an empty string' exception.

I tried with a smaller subset of files and it worked.

Bottomline, one possible cause for this exception is running out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

I my case, there is a hive property which is set

### set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat; in .hiverc file which is throwing the exception.

Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.(Path.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat$HiveInputSplit.getPath(HiveInputFormat.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.updateJobWithSplit(MapTask.java:463)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

---

After changing it to below, it worked
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat;

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. My `hive.log` file showed the cause - see the first line in the snippet below where one of the jar file URIs contains `file://` without any path:

```
2018-05-03 04:37:43,706 INFO  [main]: mr.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:execute(309)) - adding libjars: file://,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar
2018-05-03 04:38:07,568 WARN  [main]: mapreduce.JobResourceUploader (JobResourceUploader.java:uploadFiles(64)) - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2018-05-03 04:38:07,599 ERROR [main]: exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(937)) - Job Submission failed with exception 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(Can not create a Path from an empty string)'
```

In my case, the issue was caused by a badly configured `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-env.sh` file, where `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` contained a reference to an environment variable that was not set.

For example:

```
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$EMPTY_ENV_VARIABLE,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar
```